# How can I mass-set the permissions of existing files in the new ntfs3 driver?

Tags: linux, permissions, ntfs

I've been using `ntfs-3g` for mounting for years now with the `umask=022` option to grant my user read-write access on NTFS filesystem. I switched to [the new `ntfs3` driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ntfs3.html) (on Arch Linux, kernel `5.15.4-arch1-1`), only editing `fstab` to change `ntfs-3g` to `ntfs3`. This results in my user lacking `w`rite permissions:

```
% ls -l Downloads/Pictures -d
dr-xr-xr-x 1 muru muru 249856 Nov 14 15:58 Downloads/Pictures
% df -hT Downloads/Pictures
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      ntfs3  1.9T  1.2T  672G  64% /home/muru/Downloads
```

It turns out that I *can* now set the permissions using `chmod`, so:

```
% chmod u+w Downloads/Pictures 
% ls -l Downloads/Pictures -d
drwxr-xr-x 1 muru muru 249856 Nov 14 15:58 Downloads/Pictures
```

But I have multiple NTFS filesystems and many files, and these filesystems have been disk-hopping for years now, accumulating more and more data. So I don't want to spend time running `chmod u+w -R` if I can help it.

According to the docs, the `umask`, `fmask` and `dmask` options now set permissions only for *newly* created files:

> | umask= | Controls the default permissions for files/directories created after the NTFS volume is mounted. |
> | --- | --- |
> | dmask= fmask= | Instead of specifying umask which applies both to files and directories, fmask applies only to files and dmask only to directories. |
> | noacsrules | “No access rules” mount option sets access rights for files/folders to 777 and owner/group to root. This mount option absorbs all other permissions. - Permissions change for files/folders will be reported as successful, but they will remain 777. - Owner/group change will be reported as successful, butthey will stay as root. |

I don't want 777, so `noacsrules` is out. Is there a way I can have the `ntfs3` driver just assume `0755`/`0644` for everything?

Comment: Are you still running Windows? Could it be done in Windows (in an efficient way, and visible in Linux after that)?

Comment: I still have Windows (some insider build of 11). I don't know what relation permissions set in Windows has with the one shown by ntfs3 though.

Comment: I have also some insider build of 11, but I think no Linux kernel that is new enough to test it (not yet). It might be worth checking with a single file, if some Windows file attribute (that you set in Windows) is seen by Linux with your new NTFS driver.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant in your case, but I read some time ago about a new version of Linux NTFS driver, that lets you set permissions individually, *but it made the file system Linux-only*, Windows did no longer like it. I suggest that you check with a small NTFS system (for example in a pendrive) if the modifications that you intend to do can be accepted by Windows. (If you will not use it in Windows, it might be better to move your pictures and other personal data files to a Linux file system.)